# Making simple input/output program for assignment

Tags: assembly, 6502

> Create a program that prints "You entered a one" if the user enters a
> 1,
> "You entered a two" if the user enters a 2,
> "You entered a three" if the user enters a 3.
> The program should loop until the user enters a 4, then it should exit.
>
> If a number other than 1, 2, 3, or 4 is entered the program should
> print "You entered an invalid number".

---

```
    org 0200h
    
Main:

    ldx #InMess1<
    ldy #InMess1>
    jsr 0E00Ch
    
    jsr 0E009h
    jsr 0E015h
    
CheckOne:

    cmp #1d
    bne CheckTwo
    
    ldx #OneMess<
    ldy #OneMess>
    jsr 0E00Ch
    jmp Main
    
CheckTwo:

    cmp #2d
    bne CheckThree
    
    ldx #TwoMess<
    ldy #TwoMess>
    jsr 0E00Ch
    jmp Main
    
CheckThree:

    cmp #3d
    bne CheckFour
    
    ldx #ThreeMess<
    ldy #ThreeMess>
    jsr 0E00Ch
    jmp Main
    
CheckFour:

    cmp #4d
    bne Main
    
CheckError:

    cmp #1d>
    cmp #4d<
    ldx #ErrorMess<
    ldy #ErrorMess>
    bne Main
    
    brk
    
InMess1:

    dbt 0ah,0dh
    dbt "Enter 1-4: "
    dbt 0d
    
OneMess:

    dbt 0ah,0dh
    dbt "You entered a one. "
    dbt 0d
    
TwoMess:

    dbt 0ah,0dh
    dbt "You entered a two. "
    dbt 0d
    
ThreeMess:

    dbt 0ah,0dh
    dbt "You entered a three. "
    dbt 0d
    
ErrorMess:

    dbt 0ah,0dh
    dbt "You entered an invalid number. "
    dbt 0d
    
    end
```

---

That is my full code for reference but my main problem lies in the invalid input section (error)

```
CheckError:

    cmp #1d>
    cmp #4d<
    ldx #ErrorMess<
    ldy #ErrorMess>
    bne Main
    
    brk

ErrorMess:

    dbt 0ah,0dh
    dbt "You entered an invalid number. "
    dbt 0d
    
    end
```

---

Logically, I know how to do this, but I am unaware on how to do this with 6502 assembly language, and my overall question is how exactly do I include all but 4 select numbers for the error check.

Comment: `jsr 0E00Ch` appears to be missing in `CheckError`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need `CheckError` at all. If you reach `CheckFour` then the input was something other than 1, 2 or 3. So all you need to do there is:

- if input was `4`, exit without an error;
- if input wasn't `4` then, given that you reached `CheckFour` at all you already know it also wasn't `1`, `2` or `3`. Therefore you know the input wasn't `1`, `2`, `3` or `4`. So print an error, and exit.

i.e. something like:

```
CheckFour:

    cmp #4d
    beq ValidExit

    # If here, then input wasn't 1, 2, 3 or 4.
    ldx #ErrorMess<
    ldy #ErrorMess>
    jsr 0E00Ch

ValidExit:

    end
```

That said, supposing you wanted to do a range check for absolutely any other reason, `cmp` sets the negative flag if the result of subtracting the operand from `a` is negative. So negative is set if `a` was strictly less than the operand.

So e.g.:

```
lda #4d
cmp SomeValue
bmi SomeValueWasGreaterThanFour
```

Or:

```
lda #1d
cmp SomeValue
bpl SomeValueWasLessThanOrEqualToOne
```

... and consider using carry rather than sign or `SBC` if you need to explore a larger range (cf. comments below and Peter Cordes' input).

Comment: `-128 - 1` wraps to a positive number, but `-128` is signed-less-than `1`.  Looking at just the sign bit of the output doesn't work if the subtraction wraps.  In ISAs that provide a signed-less-than condition directly, such as x86, [the condition is `SF != OF`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jcc), where OF is the signed-overflow flag.  A useful trick here might be a range check using `x-=1`, then unsigned compare `x<=3`.  Or if the input is known to be a printable ASCII char (with its sign bit clear), then yes, the sign bit works as carry-out from the low 7.

Comment: The 68000 acts similarly — the test for strictly less than is `negative != overflow`; unfortunately on a 6502 `CMP` doesn't affect overflow so if your range requires it, you might have to consider a real `SBC` instead. Regardless, I'll make a brief edit to my answer because clearly your comment is an appropriate criticism of the current version.